# sys.databases in a cursor skipping databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I've seen a bit of production code that looks like it should be fine, and works 80% of the time, but the other 20% will appear to stop returning and iterating through the list of databases for no apparent reason:

```
DECLARE c_UserDatabases CURSOR FOR
  SELECT Name
  FROM   Sys.Databases SD (NOLOCK)
  ORDER  BY Name

OPEN c_UserDatabases
FETCH Next FROM c_UserDatabases INTO @v_DatabaseName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      -- Query that takes a few minutes to run (using dynamic SQL and EXEC, etc)
      FETCH Next FROM c_UserDatabases INTO @v_DatabaseName
  END

CLOSE c_UserDatabases
DEALLOCATE c_UserDatabases
```

This is on SQL Server 2008 SP3. I've noticed articles mentioning it was iffy on some versions if you did not order by Name, but nothing to indicate this failure condition. I think we might be in a rare situation because the inner section can takes so long to run?

I'd like to know if anyone else has seen this. I'm planning on rewriting it to select into a temp table and cursor through that instead.

Comment: Why're you using NOLOCK on SYS.DATABASES?!

Comment: I didn't write the code. But I did overhear an issue where long-running cursors on the user/login table were preventing logins during long runs, and it might be have been added after that as a safeguard? Why do you ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really old question of mine but the answer was that if you are iterating Sys.Databases your cursor type should be STATIC.

Otherwise if something happens to that table while you're iterating it (i.e. backups, etc) it can skip a database. Same with sp_MSForeachDB.

Thankfully we moved past this bit long ago. And yeah, NOLOCK was taken out.

Answer (score 1):

Although undocumented, sp_MSForeachDB provides a nice way of executing queries against all DBs. Would this approach help?

```
EXEC sp_MSForeachDB '
    SELECT * FROM [?].sys.tables
'
```